# JSF2 / Primefaces layout performance

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Right now I'm using a full page layout and p:layoutUnits and page composition in my webapp. I have a fixed header with a menubar, and a content layoutunit, and that's all. It was easy to set up, but in IE (7) when I navigate to a new page the whole page reloads (visibly), the header is cleared then loaded, and - even more annoyingly - the menubar is displayed for a second with all the menuitems visible.

In other browsers this effect is not really visible, sadly, IE 7 is my target.

Now I'm thinking about saying goodbye to p:layoutUnits and implementing the layout with simple css magic and fixed div for the header - would it improve display in IE? Is there anything else I can do to make it faster and smoother? I'd like it to look like the header is not changing at all, only the content.

How about using **iframe**? Would it allow bookmarkable URLs?

Comment: Maybe you should just use simple divs. If you have Primefaces-related questions, i would suggest posting in the PrimeFaces forum: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/ There you get quick&good answers (and the developers are open for issues/requests like i experienced myself)

Comment: I thought this was a bit more general question, I will ask something a bit more specific on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question, but I'll throw in a new answer anyway...

PrimeFaces 3.0 `<p:dataTable>` supports in-table scrolling. You set a fixed height and width for the data table on your page and within that box the data table is rendered with a scrollbar. The column headers and footers stay put and you just scroll the rows. They just cleaned up some format bugs in their nightly snapshot builds that make the `<p:dataTable>` look great in IE 7. Might be worth a second look at PrimeFaces for those who (like me) have to support older IE browsers.

LINK: [PrimeFaces 3.0 Showcase (scrollable data table)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf)

Comment: In-table scrolling doesn't work in IE7 and PF3.3. Totally unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally decided to say goodbye to p:layout. I have a long table that's two or three times the size of the screen. If I put it in a scrollable layoutUnit then the scrolling is so slow that it is really annoying (tested in IE, Firefox and Chrome - equally slow). Perhaps this widget was not intended for this kind of use (displaying scrollable, long content), but now it is clear that I'll have to do a proper CSS design and stay with raw DIVs.

Nevertheless it was great for quickly putting together an application GUI that can be shown to customers.

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with layouts, follow BalusC and use simple divs/css and JSF 2.0 Templating. I started with PrimeFaces layouts and could never get it to work with complicated designs.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/